# Disposing UIImage and CGImage

Tags: memory-management, xamarin.ios, uiimage, dispose, cgimage

Do I need to dispose `UIImage`s and `CGImage`s in MonoTouch application after I've finished working with them? What are the effects of disposing either of them?

Is it safe to dispose any of them if the image is still visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using a `using` block for images like so:

```
using (var image = UIImage.FromFile ("demo.png"))
{
    //do something with your image here
    //such as passing it to an UIImageView.Image
}
```

When the object leaves that block it will get disposed automatically.

Alternatively you can call `Dispose()` on the UIImage when you know you are done using it.

If you do not dispose of them and load a lot of images you will eventually run out of memory. Loading big images with the `UIImage.FromBundle()` method is a bad idea as they are cached and you have no control over when the cache is disposed of.

If you dispose an `UIImage` which is currently shown nothing bad will happen with the `UIImageView` as it keeps its own reference to the image. So only the C# managed image is disposed of but not necessarily the Cocoatouch image.

Comment: In addition to your answer, I found [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fW_Nyq_hcZY) helpful for finding native leaks, as well as [this section](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/api_design#Memory_Management) which expands on what `Dispose` does in MonoTouch.